# Saving a textbox url to an XML file using a button in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, file, explorer

I'm looking to save a path to an XML file and load it up when the program re-opens by using a button on Winforms. I've had a look around on saving states but nothing so far seems to cut the mustard.
Below is my code

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Loading of the form 

    }
    private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog()  { Description="Select your folder"})
        {
            if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                webBrowser.Url = new Uri(fbd.SelectedPath);
            txtPath.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
            // Button used to open the folder explorer and display file path in the text box. 
        }
    }

    private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (webBrowser.CanGoBack)
            webBrowser.GoBack(); //Sends the explorer back one page providing there is a page to go back too
    }
    private void btnForward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (webBrowser.CanGoForward)
            webBrowser.GoForward(); //Sends the explorer forward one page providing there is a page to go forward too

    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void txtPath_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }       
}
```

[The save search is what I want to use to store the users chosen path.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdnWC.png)

Comment: Your `btnSave_Click` method has no code; could that be the issue?

Comment: You use user settings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings

Comment: I'm pretty beginner, that is my issue, I can't get my head round what the logic for that method would be :)

Comment: Check this out:
https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEB_enUS803US803&ei=_DVXW_THOo6W5wKPqLrwAQ&q=beginners+windows+form+tutorial+in+c%23&oq=beginners+windows+form+tutorial+in+c%23&gs_l=psy-ab.3...6662.12949.0.13171.15.15.0.0.0.0.140.1504.12j3.15.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.7.746...0j0i22i30k1j0i13k1j0i8i13i30k1.0.lvu2NpbdbkQ#kpvalbx=1

Comment: Thanks all for the help, problem has been resolved and program is running how I want it to be!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kurdy already commented the preferred approach for this; use user settings.

Using Xml directly is actually a bit harder, especially if you are a beginner.
I'll try explain it anyway because your question is about XML.

This is how you could save it using Xml, dont forget the `using System.Xml;` and `using System.IO;`:

```
        var myString = "Some string to save to XML"; // Some string to save into the xml file
        var mySavePath = @"C:\dontSaveToCRoot.xml";  // Edit this path or save it next to your exe
        var xml = new XmlDocument();                 // Create a instance of XmlDocument


        if (File.Exists(mySavePath)) // Load up the XmlDocument from file if it exists
        {
            xml.Load(mySavePath);    // Load it from the specified path
        }
        else                         // Or provide the default xml if no file exists yet.
        {
            xml.LoadXml("<root />"); // Add a <root/> element as the DocumentElement
        }

        // store your string in the xml document, by adding it as an attribute to the <root /> element
        // results in: <root my-string="myString contents" />
        xml.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("my-string", myString);

        xml.Save(mySavePath);       // Save the Xml back to the specified path.
```